How to use Maven property as Gradle variable
I am using Maven's BOM to control dependencies versions across multiple Gradle projects sharing the same platform. It all works well except for controlling the plugins versions. Some Gradle plugins (Spring Boot plugin for example) need a version matching other Spring Boot dependencies version. I am wondering if there is a way to use Maven's POM property as Gradle variable. The code below obviously doesn't work.
BOM (my-bom-1.0.0.pom):
<project>
 ....
  <properties>
    <spring-boot.version>3.3.3</spring-boot.version>
    ...
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    ...

Gradle's build.gradle
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id ("org.springframework.boot") version "${spring-boot.version}"
  
}

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
      mavenBom "my-bom:1.0.0"
  }
}

In this form ${spring-boot.version} in build.gradle cannot be resolved because it is defined in POM. I am wondering if there a way to make it available in Gradle

Here’s how you can set it up:
Step 1: Import the BOM
In your build.gradle, import the BOM as you already have:
groovy
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "my-bom:1.0.0"
    }
}

Step 2: Define a Custom Task to Read the BOM
You can create a custom task to read the BOM and extract the version:
groovy
def springBootVersion

task readBom {
    doLast {
        def pomFile = new File("${projectDir}/path/to/my-bom-1.0.0.pom")
        def pom = new XmlSlurper().parse(pomFile)
        springBootVersion = pom.properties.'spring-boot.version'.text()
    }
}

readBom.dependsOn 'assemble' // Ensure this runs before the build

Step 3: Use the Extracted Version
Now you can use the springBootVersion variable in your plugins block:
groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.springframework.boot" version springBootVersion
}


That actually doesn't work:
id "org.springframework.boot" version springBootVersion
is invalid: in plugins block variables are not allowed.

Sounds like an AI answer...
